# Finding two highest value in a row and then values in the same column but different row

Tags: r

I have a data frame and the problem is I want to find two highest value in a row and then compare those values to what another row has in those columns.

```
rows <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i")
x1 <- c(1,4,5,7,5,8,9,0,5)
x2 <- c(3,3,5,6,7,8,9,0,7)
x3 <- c(3,1,4,6,7,8,9,5,2)


df <- data.frame(x1=x1,x2=x2, x3=x3, row.names = rows)
```

Here I get the two highest values from row "a"

```
sort(df["a",], decreasing = TRUE)[1:2]
```

Then I would want to find values in row "e" that belongs to these columns where "a" have the top 2 values (and in the same order).

Comment: And what should be the output?

Comment: For example if rows are "a" and "e", output should be 3 3 7 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** `order` applied to row `a` gives the vector which when used as an index to its argument will give it in sorted order so apply that to row `e` and take the last 2 elements.

```
o <- order( df["a", ] )
tail(unlist( df["e", o] ), 2)
## x2 x3 
##  7  7
```

**2)** Another possibility if s is the result shown in the question is to index `df` by its names.

```
s <- sort(df["a",], decreasing = TRUE)[1:2]
df["e", names(s)]
## x2 x3 
##  7  7
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with r but from an theoretical aspect you need an algorithm, that swaps the whole column based on the two highest values of a.

After that the values in the other rows, you want to compare to, will always be on column 1 and 2.

Comment: If you want to post this it should be as a comment. An answer needs code.that solves the problem.